# Looking for rating star plugin

Tags: ionic3, components, rating

I'm looking for a stars rating plugin or component for Ionic v3. But the plugin must allow the selection of half star.

I found some plugin but only with full stars...

Comment: Try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-rating

Comment: I've already try this one and I can only choose full stars and not empty. I can set half but I can't click on half...